# join (wordpress) meta table with missing rows

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

using wordpress user meta, wp_usermeta. (Note there is a umeta_id unique Id in the table I'm not showing here.) I'm trying to select two values in one query so I don't have to do two separate queries. The ext_id will always exist. I want to insert the img_url if it doesn't exist or update if it does.

Data e.g.

```
user_id meta_key meta_value
1       ext_id   1090392
2       ext_id   1090393
```

and I want to retrieve
user_id, ext_id, img_url

I can create a query if I have img_url meta_key and values in the table, but I don't yet, I want to populate and update them on subsequent runs.

Just to be sure I'm clear, let's say after a few runs I have:

```
user_id meta_key meta_value
1       ext_id   1090392
2       ext_id   1090393
1       img_url  "mysite.com/image1.png"
```

I would want the following returned:

```
1 1090392 "mysite.com/image1.png"
2 1090393 null
```

hope that makes sense,
thanx for your time.

Comment: be sure to click the check mark underneath the up/down vote buttons if it answers your question (this will 'accept' the answer), you can also optionally up vote it too.  Leave a comment to let me know if it needs any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh.. I no longer have WP installed to test it out but I suspect this query would work:

```
SELECT m1.user_id
, m1.ext_id
, m2.meta_value AS img_url
FROM wp_usermeta m1
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta m2 ON m1.user_id=m2.user_id AND m2.meta_key='img_url'
WHERE m1.meta_key='ext_id'
```

Comment: thanx clayton but zero rows returned. I was close to what you have but without the second condition on the left join. Oh yes, ext_id is a meta_key rather than a column. I'm currently trying variations on your theme, but if the ext_id info makes a difference I'd appreciate a head's up. thanx for your time nik.

Comment: I ended up with:

SELECT m1.user_id
, m1.meta_value as ext_id
, m2.meta_value AS img_url
FROM wp_usermeta m1
LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta m2 ON m1.user_id=m2.user_id and m2.meta_key = 'img_url'
WHERE m1.meta_key='ext_id'

thanx again for your help